# Strange behaviour in integral function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I create two functions fx and fy as follows:

```
fx = @(x) ncx2pdf(x, 10, 1);
fy = @(y) ncx2pdf(y + 25, 10, 10);
```

Then, I define fs function as follows:

```
shift = 0
fs = @(s) fx(s) .* fy(shift - s)
```

Note that fs is always positive (product of two probability density function). If I compute:

```
integral(fs, -Inf, 100)
```

I obtain the true value 0.0413, but If I compute

```
integral(fs, -Inf, 1000)
```

I obtain 0. Why this strange behavior happens using integral function? Note that if I compute

```
integral(fs, -Inf, Inf)
```

I obtain the true value 0.0413.

Comment: "Why" is indeed a good question! But as a first workaround you could consider `trapz`: e.g. `trapz(fs(-1000:1000))`

Comment: I believe the error (returning 0) comes from trying to represent a value smaller than a `double` is able to hold.  The min value is on the order of `Xe-308` per Matlab documentation.  I was able to produce 1.9e-323 before all I got back was 0.

Comment: @Matt is probably on the right track.  You have to be careful with numerical integration of functions with small values.  I've seen this in other languages, too.  So to verify,  calculate the value of one "slice" of the numerical integration function and see what its value is.

Comment: what can you tell us about `ncx2pdf`?

Comment: @transversalitycondition  it's in the Statistics Toolbox  http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/toolbox/stats/ncx2pdf.html   .  Say "thank you" to MathWorks for charging a king's ransom for additional functionality.

Comment: If you are interested, you can take a look at this Mathworks link: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/242910-strange-behaviour-in-integral-function-in-matlab#answer_192302

Comment: @bassir you should re-post the answer of your link here, with a **clear and complete reference**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Numeric quadrature works by iteratively splitting the interval apart and approximating the integral of each partition. The approximation is done by discretizing the subintervals and using some form of integral approximation (Riemann sums etc.). Since there is some discretization, there will be some error and this is dependent on the partitioning, therefore we are best to keep our limits of integration closer to the points which will contribute most to the integral.", Brendan Hamm

Ref: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/242910-strange-behaviour-in-integral-function-in-matlab#answer_192302